# interpolation not working in recursive vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have two jasons that are linked by one of them with a key. One of the jasons contains a structure that needs to be rendered recursively. The same jason contains the data that is passed to data(). And when I try to insert a string containing variable names into the template, the interpolation does not happen.

base component

```html
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <jsonvuecomponent
      v-for="js in midle_json"
      :key="js.index"
      :midle_json="js"
      :low_json="low_json"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jsonvuecomponent from "@/components/jsonvuecomponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "default",
  components: { jsonvuecomponent },
  data() {
    return {
      midle_json: {
        "unit-element1": {
          index: 1,
          component: "component1",
          type: "unit",
          properties: {
            text: "hello nekit",
            name: "city",
            placeholder: "Введите ваш город",
          },
        },
        "unit-element2": {
          component: "component2",
          index: 2,
          type: "unit",
          properties: {
            name: "city",
            placeholder: "Введите ваш городffffffff",
          },
        },
        "group-element": {
          component: "container_component1",
          index: 3,
          type: "group",
          properties: {
            color: "black",
          },
          content: {
            "unit-element3": {
              index: 1,
              component: "component3",
              type: "unit",
              properties: {
                stal: "radio",
                placeholder: "NASHMI",
              },
            },
            "unit-element4": {
              index: 2,
              component: "component2",
              type: "unit",
              properties: {},
            },
            "group-element2": {
              index: 3,
              component: "container-component1",
              type: "group",
              properties: {
                color: "red",
              },
              content: {
                "unit-element5": {
                  index: 4,
                  component: "component5",
                  type: "unit",
                  properties: {},
                },
                "unit-element6": {
                  index: 5,
                  component: "component5",
                  type: "unit",
                  properties: {},
                },
              },
            },
          },
        }, 
      },
      low_json: {
        component1: {
          template:
            "<div> {{ properties.text }} </div><input type='text' placeholder ='{{properties.placeholder}}'>",
        },
        component2: {
          template:
            "<div class='black_square' style='width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black'></div>",
        },
        component5: {
          template:
            "<div class='red_square' style='width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: pink'></div>",
        },
        container_component1: {
          template:
            "<div style='background-color: {{properties.color}}'></div>",
        },
        component3: {
          template: "<input type='{{stal}}'>{{properties.placeholder}}",
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

recursion component

```html
<template>
  <div class="сomponent">
    <!-- <div ref="component"></div> -->
    <div v-html="content"></div>
    <div v-if="midle_json.type === 'group' ? true : false">
      <jsonvuecomponent
        v-for="js in midle_json.content"
        :key="js.index"
        :midle_json="js"
        :low_json="low_json"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "jsonvuecomponent",
  data() {
    return {
      properties: this.midle_json.properties,
      content: "",
    };
  },
  props: {
    midle_json: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
      required: true,
    },
    low_json: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    compose() {
      if (this.midle_json.component in this.low_json) {
        // this.$refs.component.innerHTML =this.low_json[this.midle_json.component].template;
        // console.log(this.low_json[this.midle_json.component].template);
        this.content = this.low_json[this.midle_json.component].template;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.compose();
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

result

[image]

`<div v-html="content"></div>` and `v-text` don't work, neither does `this.$refs.component.innerHTML` where component is in turn as an empty string in data()

Comment: Data bindings don't work with v-html.

Comment: I read about the "renderToString" function and I think that it can help me, but I don’t know how it would be more correct to write it in my case

Comment: That's for SSR so not sure it's going to work for you.  Are the templates defined or random?  If they're defined just create components for each and render the correct one.  If it's random it's going to be much harder but you could do manual find/replaces before rendering.

Comment: solution: "v-runtime-template"